# Code Works Well in Main Method but When I Try to Give Its Own Method I Get Compiler Error in Regards to IOExceptionWhen Calling the Method

Tags: java, google-maps, ioexception

I thank everyone in advance for looking at this and hopefully this is any easy question to answer. I am in the process of learning Java and found a cool piece of code on the internet from http://code.runnable.com/Uu83dm5vSScIAACw/download-a-file-from-the-web-for-java-files-and-save

### I modified it to basically call up a Google Static Map and then save it as a jpg. With this code it works perfectly

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;


public class DownloadFile2 {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

         String fileName = "mapimg.jpg"; //The file that will be     saved on your computer
         URL link = new     URL("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?    center=44.667066,+-90.173632&zoom=13&scale=false&size=600x300&maptype=roa    dmap&format=png&visual_refresh=true&markers=size:mid%7Ccolor:0xff0000%7Cl    abel:0%7C44.667066,+-90.173632"); //The file that you want to download

     //Code to download
         InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(link.openStream());
         ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
         int n = 0;
         while (-1!=(n=in.read(buf)))
         {
            out.write(buf, 0, n);
         }
         out.close();
         in.close();
         byte[] response = out.toByteArray();

         FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
         fos.write(response);
         fos.close();
     //End download code

         System.out.println("Finished");

    }

}
```

---

Now this code runs great in the main method. What I am trying to do is put it in its own method and then call it from the main method like such:

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;


public class DownloadFile3 {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        getMap();
    }

    public static void getMap() throws IOException
    {        
         String fileName = "mapimg.jpg"; //The file that will be     saved on your computer
         URL link = new     URL("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?    center=44.667066,+-90.173632&zoom=13&scale=false&size=600x300&maptype=roa    dmap&format=png&visual_refresh=true&markers=size:mid%7Ccolor:0xff0000%7Cl    abel:0%7C44.667066,+-90.173632"); //The file that you want to download

     //Code to download
         InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(link.openStream());
         ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
         int n = 0;
         while (-1!=(n=in.read(buf)))
         {
            out.write(buf, 0, n);
         }
         out.close();
         in.close();
         byte[] response = out.toByteArray();

         FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
         fos.write(response);
         fos.close();
     //End download code

         System.out.println("Finished");

    }

}
```

---

It will compile fine without the getMap(); in the main method, but when I call that method, I get the following compiler error, "DownloadFile3.java:13: error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown"

I have tried using the try and catch statements and have researched this for days. I'm really stumped on this one and I'm guessing it's probably glaring obvious to a more experienced programmer on here. How come I can get it to work fine in the main method, but in its own method it will not work and give me that error message? Am I calling the method incorrectly or what is going on? I appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Well, did you `try` the call itself?

Comment: I wrapped the code in the method with try { } and then did catch { // do nothing }. I get a bunch of errors:

DownloadFile3.java:43: error: '(' expected
  catch
       ^
DownloadFile3.java:44: error: illegal start of type
  {
  ^
DownloadFile3.java:44: error: <identifier> expected
  {
   ^
DownloadFile3.java:46: error: ')' expected
  }
   ^
DownloadFile3.java:48: error: '{' expected
 }
  ^
DownloadFile3.java:50: error: reached end of file while parsing
}
 ^
DownloadFile3.java:51: error: reached end of file while parsing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few choices here. Either...

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    getMap();
}
```

or

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try {
        getMap();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

or catch and handle any exceptions in the `getMap()` method itself. My personal choice would be the second or third option; there's something I don't like about having a `main` with a `throws` clause.

Comment: I ended up using the second option doing the try and catch statements in the main method. It then compiled and worked like a charm. I think where I was going wrong on this is I thought catch and try needed to be in the method that was being called and not in the method that was doing the calling.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone and I will study everyone's solutions.

Comment: It can be either way. You could catch them inside the other method, then you wouldn't have to necessarily have the `throws` there which would mean you wouldn't need it in main either. Depends on how you want to go about it. @cody_e

Answer (score -1):

I tried the following snippet in intelliJ idea and it compiled just fine. It threw though an IOException, which is alright, because I got a 400 response code from the server.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try {
        getMap();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

There is yet another possibility:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    getMap();
}
```

Both compiled correctly in my laptop.

Comment: Where'd you get the snippet?

Comment: I pasted the question code in intelliJ, got a red underline and followed the indications

Comment: Why exactly did you give me a negative vote if my answer is correct?

Comment: "I pasted the question code in intelliJ, got a red underline and followed the indications" - always step #1. Good job!

Comment: I tried to vote both as positive, but since I'm new, I do not think it was me. The only other thing I did was check the solution for this one first but since I went at @ChiefTwoPencils solution, I checked that one instead. I don't think it should have given a -1 for doing that, but if it did I apologize.

Comment: I'm not sure why the two of you are so concerned about a down vote but you shouldn't *assume* you know who did it. There's millions of users here. And  @cody the site doesn't penalize you for changing your mind, humans cast votes.